# Chart.js Pi chart Hovering not show value as tooltip : thymeleaf, Spring boot

Tags: javascript, css, spring-boot, charts, thymeleaf

My application is a MVC application by using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, jQuery, VueJs. I have also used BootsTrap.

To show some value in a PI chart, I have used ChartJS. I have a fixed layout for all pages : a side bar, header, footer. All these included by Thymeleaf fragment.

Now, PI chart is working fine, when it is being used in a independent page, where no layout is being used. Hovering the PI chart is showing each section value.

But the problem is, when I was using with the lay out. the PI chart is showing, but when hovering it, it is not showing individual section value of the PI as toop tip.

**Main Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="card/layouts/main/main-layout">
    <style href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
<title>Welcome to RO Dashboard</title>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-wrapper" layout:fragment="content">
    <section class="content-custom" >
        <div class="col-md-12 content-midle-scroll">
            <h3 th:if="${ro == null}" style="text-align:center">RO Dashboard</h3>

            <div th:replace="salesMonitoring/dashboard/ro_dashboard/general_view_for_preview :: frag-general-view-PreView"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/user_panel.js}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`layout:decorator="card/layouts/main/main-layout"` this line is loading the layout.

**Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
    <meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

    <link rel="icon" th:href="@{/img/index.ico}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/img/index.ico}" type="image/ico" />
    <title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE $DECORATOR_TITLE"></title>

    <!-- Final CSS Start -->
    
    //bootstrap
    //other css
    
   
    <!-- Final CSS End -->

    //other java Script. 
   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        window.context = /*[[${context}]]*/ "";
        window.csrfToken = /*[[${_csrf.token}]]*/ "";
        window.csrfHeader = /*[[${_csrf.headerName}]]*/ "";
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</head>

<body style="font-size: 13px; zoom:85%" class="hold-transition skin-green sidebar-mini">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Main Header -->
        <div th:replace="card/layouts/header/main-header :: header-main"></div>
        <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
        <div th:replace="card/layouts/navigation/main-sidebar :: sidebar-main"></div>
        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div layout:fragment="content"><!-- <section >Page content goes here</section> --></div>
        <!-- Main Footer -->
        <div th:replace="card/layouts/footer/main-footer :: footer-main"></div>
        <!-- Control Sidebar -->
        <div th:replace="card/layouts/control/control-sidebar :: sidebar-control"></div>
        <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div>

    //Java Script

    <!--<div layout:fragment="custom-js"></div>-->

</body>
</html>
```

For simplicity, I have not written all the CSS and Script. I have tried by commenting each CSS and JavaScript. I have when i am using this line, problem is happening. But this line must have to used to render the content.

```
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div layout:fragment="content"><!-- <section >Page content goes here</section>
```

**Main Chart Fragment**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
    <title>General Info-View</title>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>
<div id="layout-generalPreview" th:fragment="frag-general-view-PreView">
    <div class="loandetail-area-sp box box-primary">
        <style>
            * {box-sizing: border-box;}
            ul {list-style-type: none;}
            body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}

            .month {
                padding: 25px 25px;
                width: 100%;
                background: #1abc9c;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .month ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .month ul li {
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 3px;
            }

            .month .prev {
                float: left;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }

            .month .next {
                float: right;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }

            .weekdays {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px 0;
                background-color: #ddd;
            }

            .weekdays li {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 11%;
                color: #666;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .days {
                padding: 7px 0;
                background: #eee;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .days li {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 13.6%;
                text-align: center;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                font-size:12px;
                color: #777;
            }

            .days li .active {
                padding: 5px;
                background: #1abc9c;
                color: white !important
            }

            /* Add media queries for smaller screens */
            @media screen and (max-width:720px) {
                .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
                .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
                .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
                .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
            }
        </style>
        <div class="row" style="margin: 15px">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="month">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
                        <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
                        <li>
                            February<br>
                            <span style="font-size:18px">2021</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <ul class="weekdays">
                    <li>Mo</li>
                    <li>Tu</li>
                    <li>We</li>
                    <li>Th</li>
                    <li>Fr</li>
                    <li>Sa</li>
                    <li>Su</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="days">
                    <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li>
                    <li>9</li><li><span class="active">10</span></li><li>11</li><li>12</li>
                    <li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li>
                    <li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li><li>26</li><li>27</li><li>28</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--chart pi-->
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="height: 100%">
                <!--<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;"></canvas>-->
                <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
            </div>
            <!--chart line-->
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 100%">
                <canvas id="myChartLine" style="width:100%"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script>

                // pice chart
                var xValue = ["Overdue", "TDR", "DPS", "Regular"];
                var yValues = [10, 15, 25, 45];
                var barColors = [
                    "#ffc000",
                    "#a5a5a5",
                    "#ed7d31",
                    "#4472c4"
                ];

                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart'); // node
                // var myChart = new Chart("myChart", {
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: "pie",
                    data: {
                        labels: xValue,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Dataset 1',
                            backgroundColor: barColors,
                            data: yValues
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: "Overall Sales"
                        },
                        // maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        legend: {
                            position: "left",
                            align: "end"
                        }
                    }
                });


                // line chart
                var xValues = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

                new Chart("myChartLine", {
                    type: "line",
                    data: {
                        labels: xValues,
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [5,2.5,2.7,6,7,8,6,9,7,9],
                            borderColor: "#4054e3",
                            lebel:'Aliqui',
                            fill: false
                        },{
                            lebel:'Aliqui',
                            data: [10,5.5,7.7,8,9,9,6,5,4,6],
                            borderColor: "#e11f43",
                            fill: false
                        },{
                            lebel:'Aliqui',
                            data: [9,8.5,6.7,6,7,9,6,5,4,6],
                            borderColor: "#87d3eb",
                            fill: false
                        },{
                            lebel:'Aliqui',
                            data: [3,4.5,5.7,6,9,8,6,7,5,3],
                            borderColor: "#00b5a6",
                            fill: false
                        }]

                    },
                    options: {
                        legend: {display: false},
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have printed the `ctx` varriable, it is showing value.